# why lpstrFile is returning address in memory instead of char array in OPENFILENAMEW struct?

Tags: c++, winapi, buffer

This code should compile without errors you should link `-lcomdlg32` for dialogs. The program returns: `0x22fcd8` or `68` if I use pointer. And should (I think) return the name of the file user types in dialog box.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH] = {0};
  OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
  ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
  ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
  ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
  ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
  GetSaveFileNameW(&ofn);

  using namespace std;
  cout << szFileName << endl;
  cout << *szFileName << endl; // also a number not a string
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `wcout` if you want to output an array of `wchar_t` as a null-terminated wide string.

Answer (score 2):

`cout` does not support `wchar_t` or `wchar_t*`, but it does support `int` and `void*`.  The compiler ends up converting the `wchar_t` into an int, and degrading the `wchar_t*` to a `void*`.  That is why you see `cout` print the numeric value of the `wchar_t` and the memory address of the `wchar_t*`.

Use `wcout` instead.  It supports `wchar_t` and `wchar_t*`, so it can print the actual data instead:

```
wcout << szFileName << endl;
wcout << *szFileName << endl;
```